# Check if dynamically added element is ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to find a way for checking if a dynamically added HTML element is ready.

I have a button that when clicked, it starts to animate and on-click it recreates existing iframe. The idea to do that is new iframe comes with something needed in it. 
I want to check if the iframe ready (not added but real mean, is the elements in it loaded?) and stop the animation.

Have any idea?

```
var frm = $('#allin');
frm.submit(function (ev) {
    $('#loading').show(); //here I show the loading animate
    $.ajax({
        type: frm.attr('method'),
        url: frm.attr('action'),
        data: frm.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            $('#framewrap').html('');
            var nfr = document.createElement('iframe');
            $(nfr).attr('src','iframe.php');
            $(nfr).attr('id','frame');
            $(nfr).attr('class','grid');
            $('#framewrap').html(nfr);
            $('#frame').ready(function(){
            $('#loading').fadeOut(); //here I wanted to stop it
            });
        }
    });

    ev.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Assuming you can control of what's loaded in the iframe, you can post a message from the iframe to the parent window once the iframe is ready.

Comment: So put a $(document').ready(function(){ into the iframe and when it is ready the functipn will be sending some kind var or something? how would it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put this code into iframe

```
$(document).ready(function() {
window.parent.postMessage('load complete', 'http://jahsdjhasjkdasdjkas.com');
});
```

and this into main page

```
window.addEventListener('message', receiveMessage, false);
function loadinghide(){
$('#loading').fadeOut();
};

function receiveMessage(evt)
{
  if (evt.origin === 'ajhsdjashdjkasdas.com')
  {
    loadinghide();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use iframe on load

```
document.getElementById('iframe').onload = function() {
    stopAnimation();
}
```

Comment: But there is an iframe and iframe onload function gets existing iframe as referance.

Comment: can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: There already is an i frame with same name and i cannot change the id of the iframe everytime because function maybe fired many times. so in you code, js suppose that iframe is the one existed and already loaded and ready to use then pass the code through.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to check whether to check whether the content of an `iframe` has *fully* loaded is using the `load` event, just as [@Gaafar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45905248/6313073) proposes:

```
$("#iframe").on("load", function() {
   // code to execute after the content has loaded.
}
```

While your own [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45908056/6313073) suggests a viable alternative, it's not really the best option, because unless the content of both the parent window and the `iframe` are served by the same domain you will be blocked due to the [`Same-Origin Policy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). So this solution has no value for other users that may be serving external iframes.

---

So, your code can be edited until it reaches the following optimal form:

```
var frm = $("#allin");
frm.submit(function(ev) {
  /* Show the loading. */
  $("#loading").show();

  /* Send an AJAX request. */
  $.ajax({
    type: frm.attr("method"),
    url: frm.attr("action"),
    data: frm.serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
      /* Create the iframe and set its properties. */
      var nfr = $("<iframe>", {
        "id": "frame",
        "class": "grid",
        "src": "iframe.php",
      });

      /* Set the 'load' event. */
      nfr.on("load", function () {
        /* Fade the loading out. */
        $("#loading").fadeOut();
      });

      /* Empty framewrap and the append the created iframe. */
      $("#framewrap").empty().append(nfr);
    }
  });

  /* Prevent the default behaviour. */
  ev.preventDefault();
});
```

---

I've created a simple snippet to help illustrate my point using a `timeout` instead of an `XMLHttpRequest` for simplicity:

**Snippet:**

```js
/* ----- JavaScript ----- */
setTimeout(function () {
  /* Create the iframe and set its properties. */
  var nfr = $("<iframe>", {
    "id": "frame",
    "class": "grid",
    "src": "https://example.com",
  });

  /* Set the 'load' event. */
  nfr.on("load", function () {
    /* Fade the loading out. */
    $("#loading").fadeOut();
  });

  /* Empty framewrap and the append the created iframe. */
  $("#framewrap").empty().append(nfr);
}, 1000);
```

```css
/* ----- CSS ----- */
#loading {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  background: black;
}

#frame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<!----- HTML ----->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "framewrap"></div>
<div id = "loading"></div>
```

---

As you have mentioned in a comment of yours, *"There already is an iframe with same name..."*, an `iframe` with the same name already exists and that's why `load` doesn't work for you.

I'm not sure exactly what you mean, because you say the `iframe` already exists, but you create it *(again?)* in the code you have added to your question, but the following snippet proves that even though the `iframe` may exist before the `load` event listener is attached by just changing the `src` attribute you can get it to work:

**Snippet:**

```js
/* ----- JavaScript ----- */
setTimeout(function () {
  /* Cache the iframe. */
  var nfr = $("#frame");
  
  /* Res-set the 'src' attribute. */
  nfr[0].src = nfr[0].src;
  
  /* Set the 'load' event. */
  $("#frame").on("load", function () {
    /* Fade the loading out. */
    $("#loading").fadeOut();
  });
}, 1000);
```

```css
/* ----- CSS ----- */
#loading {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  background: black;
}

#frame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<!----- HTML ----->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "framewrap">
  <iframe id = "frame" class = "grid" src = "https://example.com"></iframe>
</div>
<div id = "loading"></div>
```