# Access iframe after it just was appended

Tags: javascript, jquery

My version that does not work:

```
 $(window).on('load', function() {
      var $iframe = $("<iframe>", 
                 {id:"up2europe",
                 marginheight:"5",
                 marginwidth:"5",
                 src:"https://www.up2europe.eu/widget/go/181d4bdc08289da3d78b79ee5f9e7e2d"
                 }); 

       $(".sidebar__right:first").append($iframe).on('load', function() 
             alert(document.getElementbyId("#up2europe").documentElement.title);                                                                                                
       });
});
```

So... I'm trying to access the title of the iframe...to check if it was loaded properly.

Comment: `getElementbyId("up2europe")`, `#` is not required in `getElementbyId()`

Comment: `getElementbyId("#up2europe")` need to be `getElementbyId("up2europe")` (remove `#`)

Comment: Also `{` is missed here:- `$(".sidebar__right:first").append($iframe).on('load', function() `

Comment: Do you call this code from `https://www.up2europe.eu`? If not, you will be running against same-origin policies. (when you'll have fixed all the typos you've got).

Comment: getElementbyId("up2europe")  did not worked.

Comment: @Kaiido I don't call this code from https://www.up2europe.eu, so running against same-origin policies will prevent me to fix this?

Comment: Yes, you simply can't acess the contenDocument of an iframe pointing to an external document. But the onload event  should fire which should be enough for your case.

Comment: I've read all answers given but all of them are a far cry from helping you achieve what you want @anon123. Check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47629031/6313073), but be forewarned that, unless both the content of the `iframe` and the parent window are served from the same domain, you'll hit the `Same-Origin Policy` wall head on.

Answer (score 0):

There are more a couple of things wrong with your code:

1. You use `$("...").append($iframe)` which returns `$("...")` after the `iframe` is appended. That means that your `load` event is attached to `$("...")` rather than the `iframe` which is the logical thing to do in this case. To achieve that use `$iframe.appendTo("...")`, so that the return value of the method is `$iframe`.
2. You use `getElementbyId` inside the aforementioned `load` event listener which is basically the wrong way to write `getElementById`.
3. The argument you pass to `alert` inside the event listener isn't an effective way to get the `title` of the document of the `iframe`.

So, by correcting the above errors the code becomes:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
  /* Create the iframe. */
  var $iframe = $("<iframe>", {
    id: "up2europe",
    marginheight: "5",
    marginwidth: "5",
    src: "https://www.up2europe.eu/widget/go/181d4bdc08289da3d78b79ee5f9e7e2d"
  });

  /* Using 'appendTo' ensures we add the 'load' event listener to the iframe. */
  $iframe.appendTo(".sidebar__right:first").on('load', function() {
    /* 'this' refers to the iframe. */
    alert(this.contentDocument.title);
  });
```

**Note:** In order to actually get the `title` of the document of the `iframe` both the content of the `iframe` and the parent window must be served by the same domain, otherwise your code will fail due to the `Same-Origin Policy`.

**Snippet:**

*<sub>(Getting the document title fails due to the same-origin policy; read the error thrown.)</sub>*

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  /* Create the iframe. */
  var $iframe = $("<iframe>", {
    id: "up2europe",
    marginheight: "5",
    marginwidth: "5",
    src: "https://www.up2europe.eu/widget/go/181d4bdc08289da3d78b79ee5f9e7e2d"
  });

  /* Using 'appendTo' ensures we add the 'load' event listener to the iframe. */
  $iframe.appendTo(".sidebar__right:first").on('load', function() {
    /* 'this' refers to the iframe. */
    alert(this.contentDocument.title);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "sidebar__right"></div>
```

---

**Resource:** You can read more about the `Same-Origin Policy` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

---

If you only want to check whether the content of an `iframe` has loaded, you don't need to check its document's `title`, but rather simply attach a `load` event`:

```
$iframe.on("load", function () {
   // code to execute after it's loaded.
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe this is the right method to add an element with jQuery. Check out from this [**LINK**](http://cr8code.co/editor.php?workid=0cccd1d7be3197a0f7e6b9a78f79b9ad).

**Code:**

```
 $(window).on('load', function() {
   var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
   $(iframe).css({'marginheight':'5px','marginwidth':'5px'});
   $(iframe).attr({'src':'https://www.up2europe.eu/widget/go/181d4bdc08289da3d78b79ee5f9e7e2d','id':'up2europe','title':'Im iframe'});
   $(".sidebar__right").append(iframe);

    $(iframe).ready(function(){
       alert($(iframe).attr('title'));
    });

 });
```

Comment: But in the question he said "to check if it was loaded properly". and i dont know which part of the content's title he is trying to get. Also this is even not the proper way to check if the iframe is loaded. the best way is postMessage and receiveMessage method but it is only avaiable if the loaded frame is yours and you can add postMessage script in it. @AngelPolitis

Comment: `postMessage` and `receiveMessage` are used for cross-communication between `iframe` elements; you don't need them to check whether an `iframe` has loaded, neither does it have to be yours. A simple `$iframe.load()` is enough to check whether its content has loaded. It only has to be yours, if your intent is to manipulate its content.

Comment: You can check if the iframe is added but you cannot check if the src link is loaded inside and fully ready without postMessage method and yes it has to be your to add the js code in it to make source post the message to the parent window. @AngelPolitis

Comment: You're simply wrong! A simple [Google Search](https://www.google.gr/search?rlz=1C1GGRV_enGR751GR751&ei=GQwlWuGoMoqd6ASJ5YPQAQ&q=check+if+an+iframe+has+loaded&oq=check+if+an+iframe+has+loaded&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i5i30k1.2911.5791.0.6132.4.4.0.0.0.0.156.413.0j3.3.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..1.3.411...0i19k1j0i22i30i19k1j0i7i5i30k1.0.T7oNo4coCj4) will suffice to show you. That's what the `load` event does; it checks whether the content of an element has loaded. `postMessage` and `receiveMessage` are used for cross-communication between different windows.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45905205/check-if-dynamically-added-element-is-ready this was my question and the load method didnt work. cr8code.co is mine and i was trying to stop an animation on parent window upon successfull loading of the iframe but i was unable to do with load. Thats why im claiming that the best method for this is; postMessage.@AngelPolitis

Comment: I'm not saying your method is wrong. I'm saying you are wrong saying that _you cannot check if the `src` link is loaded inside and fully ready without `postMessage`_. Also, your method is not the best, because it only works, if both the parent and the `iframe` are served from the same domain. Using `load` works for everyone 

I also posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47630953/6313073) to your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45905205/6313073) that highlights the functionality of `load`. I hope you find it useful.